# Consulta DATETIME por dias

Tags: sql

Necesito hacer una búsqueda por días, es decir que me aparezca un campo en concreto filtrado por X día y salgan las horas

En resumen me gustaría hacer query que me muestre el todos los registros de hoy, y que muestre también la hora. Tengo este query hecha pero solo me muestra los días y los registros con hora del mismo día no me los muestra.

```
 SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `fechahora` = '2020-09-25'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: para que base de datos?

Comment: Parece mySQL, por los acentos invertidos.

Answer (score 1):

lo que podés hacer para buscar por fecha es poner los signos de mayor o menor en lugar del igual, el igual solamente te va a devolver todo lo que, valga la redundancia, sea igual, si querés que la consulta te devuelva los datos de hoy, entonces tendrías que hacerlo de esta forma:

```
 SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `fechahora` > '2020-09-25';
```

O podrías utilizar las funciones de tiempo que ofrece SQL, como ser [CURRENT_DATE](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-date-functions/sql-current-date/) para que sea en la fecha de hoy, [CURRENT_TIME](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-date-functions/sql-current_time/) para la hora actual o [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-date-functions/sql-current_timestamp/) para la fecha y hora actuales, quedando tu consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `fechahora` > CURRENT_DATE;
```

De esta forma va a buscar todo lo que sea mayor a la fecha de hoy. Consecuentemente podés agregar horas, minutos y segundos a la primera consulta para hacerlo más preciso.
Ahora, supongamos que querés buscar únicamente los datos del 23 de septiembre, entonces ahí deberías decirle que la fecha sea mayor al 23 y menor al 24, quedando:

```
SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `fechahora` > '2020-09-23' AND `fechahora` < '2020-09-24';
```

Te recomiendo que veas esta [página](https://www.sqltutorial.org/) en donde vas a encontrar un montón de ejemplos y tutoriales.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres especificamente los registros de hoy(día actual), sin importar la hora, es decir, desde `12 AM - 11:59 PM`, puedes extraer la `DATE` sin el `TIME` y comparar.

```
`SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE DATE(`fechahora`) = DATE(GET_DATE())`
```